# Flex,Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have google maps application in Flex.Whenever the map is clicked it calls a HTTPService internally. It is suppose to fetch data from google Rest web service in JSON format. But I am not able access the Web Service as I keep getting the error -

```
(mx.messaging.messages::ErrorMessage)#0
  body = (null)
  clientId = "DirectHTTPChannel0"
  correlationId = "2662EE9F-D349-806E-1D23-8BC4D0117C5E"
  destination = ""
  extendedData = (null)
  faultCode = "Channel.Security.Error"
  faultDetail = "Destination: DefaultHTTP"
  faultString = "Security error accessing url"
  headers = (Object)#1
    DSStatusCode = 0
  messageId = "124EF92C-AB10-2BB6-97F8-8BC4D0952DA4"
  rootCause = (flash.events::SecurityErrorEvent)#2
    bubbles = false
    cancelable = false
    currentTarget = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3
      bytesLoaded = 0
      bytesTotal = 0
      data = (null)
      dataFormat = "text"
    eventPhase = 2
    target = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3
    text = "Error #2048"
    type = "securityError"
  timestamp = 0
  timeToLive = 0
```

Comment: Are you using the Google Maps Flex component?

Answer (score 0):

Your not allowed to fetch data from a seperate domain by default with flex.

One possible solution is to proxy the services you require on your own domain.

Note however that this makes it more expensive in bandwidth terms.

Comment: can u show an example...i dont know how u can do such a thing

Comment: I can't really show you an example it depends on your server side technology. Try asking as a seprerate question here. How do I proxy a web service in [insert language here]? Chances are someone has already answered that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature of flash. What you'll need to do is edit your [security settings.](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04a.html)

Comment: Click that guys link, click Edit Locations>Add Location, and point to your flex files directory (where the swf is being executed i.e. your flex builder workspace directory). Im pretty sure Google maps API will work fine with flash when you load it to the web. Otherwise here is a proxy tutorial: http://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/flex-testingrunning-php-proxy-locally/